# Условия выбора данных в представлении для колонки со заначением NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица `ATEST` с двумя столбцами `QUESTS, COMMENTS`:

```
QUESTS      COMMENTS
-------------------------------
Вопрос 1    Тут есть данные
Вопрос 2    
Вопрос 3    
Вопрос 4    И тут есть данные
Вопрос 5
```

Надо сделать на основе этой таблицы предсттавление с одним столбцом `QUECOMM`, в котором должна быть информация:

- если в `COMMENTS` есть данные (не `NULL`), то внести данные из `ATEST.COMMENTS` (получится, 1 и 4 строки)
- если в `COMMENTS` нет данных (`NULL`), тогда брать `ATEST.QUESTS` (2, 3 и 5 строки).

То есть, сделать простое условие. Как его сделать именно в SQL?

Comment: А какие у вас трудности с условием, которое вы сами окрестили - "простое"?

Comment: К сожалению, никогда не использовал условия на SQL, поэтому точно не знаю, как применить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю так:

```
create or replace view atestview as 
    select coalesce (comments, quests) quecom
    from atest
/
```